# vuejs for developing chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, vuex

I am wondering if vuejs fits for developing chrome extensions. I have used react and redux, but I want to try something new, but I can't find so much about it. I am particularly wondering how I can use vue components with vuex to communicate between background, popup and content script.

Answer (score 0):

Using Vuejs v2 runtime build because CSP

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CSP-environments